# Link Indenting using CSS3 Animation

Tags: html, css, hover, css-animations

I am using the following code to animate some links:

```css
.indenting_links li a:hover {
  padding-left: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: padding-left 500ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: padding-left 500ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: padding-left 500ms ease-out;
  transition: padding-left 500ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class="indenting_links">
  <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 10</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Problem:** The links jump back skipping a retrieve animation.

**Code snippet:** [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RobUK/pen/GRoeBpe)

I found a translation online from a Russian website which says:

> And if you add this effect not to: hover, but to the element itself,
> then there will also be no jump on return

but I have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you should set the transition in the default state, not the hover state:

```css
.indenting_links li a:hover {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.indenting_links li a {
  -webkit-transition: padding-left 500ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: padding-left 500ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: padding-left 500ms ease-out;
  transition: padding-left 500ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class="indenting_links">
  <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 10</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you just had the transition in the hover state, when the mouse leave the element the transition rule is lost, hence the jump. By putting the transition on the alement regardless of the state, the transition will always be applied.